# jQuery Post JSON.Stringify() payload is not JSON, Indexing all characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So, this is driving me nuts and I've never seen this before. I'm using Javascript to post JSON to AWS Lambda. The issue is that the payload is being sent as indexed characters instead of JSON. I can't for the life of me figure out why. I use this same code in another project and don't have this issue with posting JSON. This is what is being sent:

```
0=%7B&1=%22&2=C&3=o&4=m&5=p&6=a&7=n&8=y&9=N&10=a&11=m&12=e&13=%22&14=%3A&15=%22&16=R&17=T&18=S&19=%22&20=%2C&21=%22&22=F&23=i&24=r&25=s&26=t&27=N&28=a&29=m&30=e.....
```

As you can see it's indexing every single character of the data.
Here's my function:

```
$.ajax({
        url: serviceUrl + "UpdateCompany",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(company),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function success(res) {
            if (res.status == "ok") {
                utils.notify("Company updated successfully");

                callback(res.data);
            }
            else {
                utils.notify(res.message);
            }
        },
        error: function error(res) {
            alert("Could not complete action. Please refresh the page and try again.");
        }
    })
```

My "company" object is created like this:

```
var company = {};
        company["CompanyName"] = $("#txtCompany").val();
        company["FirstName"] = $("#txtFirstName").val();
```

[image]

When I debug it and run JSON.stringify(company), it displays the data correctly in JSON format, but when it's sent through the POST, it's not JSON format and indexing the characters like above.

Comment: That looks like a urlencoded version of the JSON string that's converted to an array or something like that. This screenshot is created by this ajax request OR is there any other parallel form submit? What version of jquery are you using? Do you have any `$.ajaxSetup` where some default `contentType` is set?

Comment: Yes, this is the ajax request that's creating that payload. There isn't any other submit or anything going on. I'm using jquery-1.12.0. No, no other ajax pre-functions.

Comment: Could you try with a newer version of jquery?

Comment: May be your JSON includes any special strings or quotes?